# Unit testing FormGroup/FormArray

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing, form-control

I have a function that accepts an AbstractControl variable and performs the following action:

```
new(item: AbstractControl) {
  item['controls'].myArray.push(
    this.formBuilder.group({
      // my attributes here
    )}
  )
}
```

The object structure when I perform `console.log(item)` is the following (*I have only shown important info*):

```
FormGroup {
  controls: {
    …,
    items: FormArray { 
      …,
      controls: Array(5) [FormGroup, FormGroup, …] 
  }
}
```

However I cannot seem to test it properly...

```
it('Should add', () => {
    const fb = new FormBuilder();
    const myObject = fb.group([example]);

    component.new(myObject);

    const packagesLength = component.myFormGroup.get('data')['controls'][0]['controls']['items']['controls'].length;

    expect(packagesLength).toEqual(2);
  });
```

All I get from the console is

> **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

If I remove the array brackets from for my FormBuilder.group (ie `fb.group(example);`, I receive the message:

> **customer.controls.packages.push is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

Would't you need to add a formArray with the name of 'myArray' in you test rather than an array in a formGroup without a control name? So something like:

```
it('Should add', () => {
    const fb = new FormBuilder();
    const myObject = fb.group('myArray': fb.array());

    component.new(myObject);

    const packagesLength = component.myFormGroup.get('data')['controls'][0] ['controls']['items']['controls'].length;

    expect(packagesLength).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: `const myObj = fb.group('myArray': fb.array())` seems to be a little more complicated requiring the form: `fb.group({myArray': fb.array([], [], []));` where fb.array requires `controlsConfig`, `validator` and `asyncValidator`. Also doing this gives the error log: **`Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`**

Comment: But you access the formArray with myArray, so from the structure you would need a formGroup which has one control with name myArray and that contains the formArray.

Comment: the cannot read property 'controls' of undefined where is that called? within your 'new' function or when you check your packagesLength?